# Pandas: is 'pad' the same as 'ffill'?

Tags: pandas

This page seems to document `pad` and `ffill` as if they are synonymous.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html

Are there any differences between the two, or are they truly interchangable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they're synonyms for the same thing - forward filling. Fire up an IPython terminal session and type `pd.DataFrame.fillna?` to see a description of the parameters. In particular,

> `method` : {`'backfill'`, `'bfill'`, `'pad'`, `'ffill'`, `None`}, default `None`
>       Method to use for filling holes in reindexed Series
>       `pad` / `ffill`: propagate last valid observation forward to next  valid
>       `backfill` / `bfill`: use NEXT valid observation to fill gap